# All Standard Reports Missing

Tags: reporting, permissions

I have an SF instance and want to view some standard reports, but none show up even though I am an Admin and believe I have all rights to everything. What can I do?

Edit: When I look at the "Classic" view of SF, I can see all reports, but when I am in the Lightning experience, I don't see anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out (Section "folders"): https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_analytics.htm&type=0

> *Features Not Available in Lightning Experience*:
>   Standard Folders, containing default reports and dashboards that come packaged with
>   Salesforce

Comment: Crazy, why would that be? Thanks, in any case.